# How can i rewrite this string from .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've searched for this question but I only come across really specific answers that seem difficult to tailor to my specific needs.

How can I rewrite the URL's?

Now I have the URL like this: `automv.ro/anunturi-auto/?make=bmw` and I want to make it look like this `automv.ro/anunturi-auto/bmw`

I have tried with this but doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^anunturi-auto/?make= anunturi-auto/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) $1?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(anunturi-auto)/\?make=(bmw) [NC]
RewriteRule ^anunturi-auto/?$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(anunturi-auto)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1?make=$2 [L]
```

Comment: @MarianStan Can you check whether `mod-rewrite` is enabled?

Comment: Yes it's enabled `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On ...`

Comment: @MarianStan That lne only executes __if__ the module is enabled. To see whether it is actually enabled, run `sudo apachectl -M`

Comment: I don't have SSH access